# Outlook 2003 - Recurring items showing the first occurrences start/end date

Tags: c#, com, outlook

**Background**: I'm writing an application in C# (.NET 3.5), that looks at multiple users  Outlook 2003 calendars (using COM objects), gets the appointments and inserts the data for those appointments into a database.

**Problem:** After the first users calendar, any recurring items on the following calendars, will always have a start and end time of the first occurrence of that item. I'm releasing the COM Objects between users (and during, if the user has a lot of items), and The item collection is being restricted correctly (due to there only being a handful of the recurring tasks inserted (albeit the wrong start/end) instead of infinite from the "no end" tasks). The correct start/end time is part of the requirements, having the information available for this or another application to work out how much free time a user has for a given range of dates, and working hours.

**Code:** (Variable declarations omitted, they're at the top of the relevant functions)

Looping through the users (in Main()):

```
 foreach (DataRow drUserCalendar in dtCalendars.Rows)
                {
                    //for each calendar we're looking at, export their calendar data and put it in the database
                    try
                    {
                        appOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
                        ExportCalendar(drUserCalendar);
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(appOutlook);
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //report error
                    }
                }
```

Extracting information from the calendar

```
static void ExportCalendar(DataRow drUser)
        {                    
            strDisplayName = drUser["DisplayName"].ToString();
            strUserID = drUser["ID"].ToString();

            int.TryParse(drUser["PreviousDays"].ToString(), out intPrevious);
            int.TryParse(drUser["FutureDays"].ToString(), out intFuture);

            dtmAllowedPreviousStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-intPrevious);
            dtmAllowedFutureStart = DateTime.Now.AddDays(intFuture);

            nsOne = appOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            nsOne.Logon(null, null, false, false);
            rcpOne = nsOne.CreateRecipient(strDisplayName);

            intCount = 0;

            if (rcpOne.Resolve())
            {
                fldOne = nsOne.GetSharedDefaultFolder(rcpOne, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

                strRestrict = "[Start] > '" + MIN_START_DATE.ToString("g") + "' And [End] < '" + MAX_START_DATE.ToString("g") + "'";
                itms = fldOne.Items;
                itms.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);
                itms.IncludeRecurrences = true;
                itmsRestricted = itms.Restrict(strRestrict);
                itmsRestricted.Sort("[Start]", Type.Missing);
                itmsRestricted.IncludeRecurrences = true;
                blnIsRecurring = false;
                dicRecurringTaskTracker = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                foreach (object objOne in itmsRestricted)
                {

                    if (intCount >= 100 || blnIsRecurring)
                    {
                        //release COM objects. Outlook doesn't like you having more than 250 ish items without cleaning up.
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(appOutlook);
                        appOutlook = new Outlook.Application();
                        GC.Collect();
                        intCount = 0;
                    }

                    if (objOne is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
                    {
                        appItem = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)objOne;
                        blnException = false;

                        //get data from the item
                        strEntryID = appItem.EntryID;
                        strSubject = appItem.Subject;
                        strBody = appItem.Body;
                        dtmStart = appItem.Start;
                        dtmEnd = appItem.End;

                        blnException = EXCEPTIONS.Contains(strSubject);

                        //if the item is an exception we're done with it.
                        if (!blnException)
                        {
                            strRecurrenceInterval = "";
                            strRecurrenceType = "";
                            strRecurrenceInfo = "";


                            //check if it's a recurring task.
                            blnIsRecurring = appItem.IsRecurring;
                            if (blnIsRecurring)
                            {
                                //check to see if we've already had a task from this series
                                if (!dicRecurringTaskTracker.Keys.Contains(strEntryID))
                                {
                                    //Start at 0 so the first (this) task
                                    //is number 1.
                                    dicRecurringTaskTracker.Add(strEntryID, 0);
                                }

                                //update number
                                dicRecurringTaskTracker[strEntryID] += 1;
                                //change the subject to add the count on the end
                                strEntryID = strEntryID + '-' + dicRecurringTaskTracker[strEntryID].ToString();

                                //it's a recurring task, so we need to find out when/how often.
                                rpTaskRecurrence = appItem.GetRecurrencePattern();
                                rtTaskRecurrenceType = rpTaskRecurrence.RecurrenceType;
                                strRecurrenceType = rtTaskRecurrenceType.ToString();
                                strRecurrenceInterval = rpTaskRecurrence.Interval.ToString();

                                switch (strRecurrenceType)
                                {
                                    case "olRecursDaily":
                                    case "olRecursMonthNth":
                                    case "olRecursWeekly":
                                        strRecurrenceInfo = rpTaskRecurrence.DayOfWeekMask.ToString();
                                        break;
                                    case "olRecursMonthly":
                                        strRecurrenceInfo = rpTaskRecurrence.DayOfMonth.ToString();
                                        break;
                                }
                            } 

                            if (strEntryID != null && strSubject != null && dtmStart != null && dtmEnd != null
                                && (intPrevious == 0 || (dtmStart > dtmAllowedPreviousStart)) && (intFuture == 0 || (dtmStart < dtmAllowedFutureStart)))
                            {
                                //build up the SQL
                                strSQL = "EXEC UpdateCalendarEntry ";
                                strSQL += "@EntryID='" + strEntryID + "', ";
                                strSQL += "@Subject='" + strSubject.Replace("'", "''") + "', ";
                                strSQL += "@Body='" + strSubject.Replace("'", "''") + "', ";
                                strSQL += "@StartDate='" + dtmStart.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "', ";
                                strSQL += "@EndDate='" + dtmEnd.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "', ";
                                strSQL += "@UserCalendarID=" + strUserID + ",";
                                strSQL += "@Recurring = " + blnIsRecurring.ToString() + ",";
                                strSQL += "@RecurrenceType = '" + strRecurrenceType + "',";
                                strSQL += "@RecurrenceInterval = '" + strRecurrenceInterval + "',";
                                strSQL += "@RecurrenceInfo = '" + strRecurrenceInfo + "';";

                                try
                                {
                                    //Execute SQL
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    //Print error message
                                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(appItem);
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                    strEntryID = null;
                    strSubject = null;
                    strBody = null;
                    intCount++;
                }

                //finished looping, do some clean up. 
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(nsOne);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(rcpOne);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(fldOne);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(itms);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(itmsRestricted);
                GC.Collect();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not resolve name");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing I've found that the issue relates to my (or whoever runs the application) permissions on the users (shared) calendar(s) that are being looked at.

It works on the first user because that's myself in this case. It doesn't work on users after that because i don't have sufficient rights it seems (confirmed by having my colleague changing it so default users are "owners" on his calendar and running the application again, and it working for his calendar).

I have since tried to use `GetOccurrence(DateTime)` (surrounded with a while loop), however that lead to the same issue. The function would error when there was no occurrence (as expected), but when it found an occurrence it would return a null object.

However because I wasn't using the object for anything other than getting the start and end date of the task, I worked it out manually (I had the original task, meaning i could get the duration, by incrementing each day until I get an occurrence I'd get the reccurring tasks start date, and using the duration of the task I calculated the end date).

It's not an ideal solution, but if you're just wanting to get recurring tasks it's simple enough to do (though resource consuming if you have a lot of reccurring tasks and are looping for a long period of time)

Comment: Perhaps try Redemption (I believe there is a trial). I was having similar issues with the Exceptions collection, but opening up the RDOAppointmentItem and using RDO (not the OOM) and the problems are "solved" (of course, this also means I might have subtle RCW leak as well). Maybe there be similar awesomeness for you...

Answer (score 0):

I can't see an obvious problem with your code I'm afraid but as I expect your well aware there is probably some other stuff happening behind the scenes that is causing your problem.

I have covered some things I found to be best practice when I was working with this stuff in a blog article - http://jynxeddevelopment.blogspot.com. It might be worth a read to see if anything seems different to what you are doing, I think the section 'Keep references to everything' might be useful.

I'm not sure your COM objects will be collected with the GC call as you're not setting them to null first, however either way this shouldn't make a difference. I got this sort of thing working without any GC calls.

Things to look at:

- objOne should be release EVERY loop if it's a COM object (I expect it is)
- Closing your Outlook application before releasing it (appOutlook.Close()), I'm surprised your not getting lots of them hanging around
- Examine every field you are using on the COM object, if they are COM objects too they might need Finalising too

Sorry this is nothing concrete but working with this stuff is hard work :/ Good luck!

-Jynx

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfroututnatly I'm releasing all the COM Objects that are called. I've since nulled them after that and before calling the GC. I have also called the Quit method on the outlook object before releasing, nulling and calling the GC now (I was in an earlier version but it just proved to annoy me by closing my outlook...)